# Query to check where database growth was?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, storage

I have a database that grew very significantly overnight and I'd like to find out why. I've restored yesterdays backup to another location. Is there a query I can run to query the size of tables or indexes so I can compare the two?

Comment: If you don't have many tables, you can use the Disk Usage by Top Tables report in Management Studio.

Comment: @Jon unfortunately I don't have access to that. If there a way to reproduce these results via query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I profiled the query and this is the portion that returns the 'Disk Usage by Top Tables' results:

```
exec sp_executesql @stmt=N'begin try 

            SELECT TOP 1000
            (row_number() over(order by (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) desc))%2 as l1,
            a3.name AS [schemaname],
            a2.name AS [tablename],
            a1.rows as row_count,
            (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0))* 8 AS reserved,
            a1.data * 8 AS data,
            (CASE WHEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) > a1.data THEN (a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used,0)) - a1.data ELSE 0 END) * 8 AS index_size,
            (CASE WHEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) > a1.used THEN (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved,0)) - a1.used ELSE 0 END) * 8 AS unused
            FROM
            (SELECT
            ps.object_id,
            SUM (
            CASE
            WHEN (ps.index_id < 2) THEN row_count
            ELSE 0
            END
            ) AS [rows],
            SUM (ps.reserved_page_count) AS reserved,
            SUM (
            CASE
            WHEN (ps.index_id < 2) THEN (ps.in_row_data_page_count + ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
            ELSE (ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
            END
            ) AS data,
            SUM (ps.used_page_count) AS used
            FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
            GROUP BY ps.object_id) AS a1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT
            it.parent_id,
            SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS reserved,
            SUM(ps.used_page_count) AS used
            FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
            INNER JOIN sys.internal_tables it ON (it.object_id = ps.object_id)
            WHERE it.internal_type IN (202,204)
            GROUP BY it.parent_id) AS a4 ON (a4.parent_id = a1.object_id)
            INNER JOIN sys.all_objects a2  ON ( a1.object_id = a2.object_id )
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas a3 ON (a2.schema_id = a3.schema_id)
            WHERE a2.type <> N''S'' and a2.type <> N''IT''
            end try
            begin catch
            select
            -100 as l1
            ,   1 as schemaname
            ,       ERROR_NUMBER() as tablename
            ,       ERROR_SEVERITY() as row_count
            ,       ERROR_STATE() as reserved
            ,       ERROR_MESSAGE() as data
            ,       1 as index_size
            ,       1 as unused
            end catch',@params=N''
```

Comment: how do I modify the post so that the "sp_executesql @stmt=N'begin try" is part of the query?

Comment: Excellent. Fixed that line for you also :)

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know where I can find how to fix them in the future? :)

Comment: I just edited the post, highlighted all of the code and hit the code button (braces icon on the toolbar) :)

Comment: Thanks again dude, i thought I had to wrap it around, not highlight. :)